# Proving that the order of $(a,b)$ is the lcm of $|a|,|b|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to solve the following exercise from Dummit & Foote's Abstract Algebra text:

> Prove that the elements $(a,1)$ and $(1,b)$ of $A \times B$ commute and **deduce** that the order of $(a,b)$ is the least common multiple of $|a|$ and $|b|$.

The first part is easy: $$(a,1)(1,b)=(a \star 1,1 \diamond b)=(a,b)=(1 \star a,b \diamond 1)=(1,b)(a,1) $$
The second part isn't that much harder to prove. The thing is I can't see how a proof can be **deduced** by the mere fact that $(a,1)$ and $(1,b)$ commute. Is such a proof possible?

Thanks.

Comment: An example for why commuting is necessary. For $D_\infty = \langle r, s \mid s^2 = e, srs = r^{-1} \rangle$, the infinite dihedral group, both $rs$ and $s$ have order $2$, but their product, $r$ has infinite order. Oops.

Comment: @HenrySwanson I have no doubts that commutativity is necessary. I'm asking how can this fact by itself reveal the order of the product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: We have $\left(A \times \{1\}\right) \cap (\{1\} \times B) = \{(1,1)\}$. Since $(a,1)$ and $(1,b)$ commute, we have that $(a,b)^n=(a,1)^n(1,b)^n$. Since the order of $(a,1)$ is $|a|$, and the order of $(1,b)$ is $|b|$, what does this tell you about the order of $(a,b)$?

Comment: That it is $\leq$ lcm of $|a|,|b|$? I'm afraid that's not enough.

Comment: @user1337 It tells you more than that.

Comment: @user1337 Oops, I think you're right. You should also need that $A \times \{1\} \cap \{1\} \times B = (1,1)$. This is trivial, though, and I assume Dummit and Foote allow you to use that in this proof.

Comment: I still don't see how this extra fact solves the problem. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @user1337 The extra fact gives us that for $(a,1)^n(1,b)^n=(1,1)$, we need $(a,1)^n=(1,1)$ and $(1,b)^n=(1,1)$ (because otherwise, $(a,1)^n$ has inverse $(1,b)^n$ and thus $(1,b)^n \in (A \times \{1\})$, which is impossible). Does that do it for you?

Comment: I think so. I also need the fact that if $x^n=e$ then $|x| | n$, right?

Comment: @user1337 Yup - and then the definition of LCM finishes the job.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ \ 1 = (a,b)^k = (a,1)^k (1,b)^k\iff (a,1)^k = (1,b)^{-k}\in \langle(a,1)\rangle\cap \langle (1,b)\rangle = \{(1,1)\}$

$\qquad\  \iff (a,1)^k = (1,1) = (1,b)^k\iff|a|,\,|b|\mid k\iff {\rm lcm}(|a|,|b|)\mid k$